# Resetting a form in IE8 causes select input to fire 4 change events when value hasn't been modified

Tags: javascript, select, input, internet-explorer-8

I'm working with the following code:

```
<form id="myform">
  <select name="myselect" id="myselect"> 
    <option value="0">Default</option>
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2" selected>Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
  </select>  
  <input type="submit" value="Go">
  <input type="reset" class="reset" value="Reset form">  
</form>

var $element = $('#myselect');

// Save current value of element
$element.data('oldVal', $element.val());

// Look for changes in the value
$element.on("change propertychange keyup input paste", function () {

    // If value has changed... (selects don't play nice -- if they've changed they obviously have to have changed, though)
    if ($element.data('oldVal') != $element.val() || $element.is('select')) {

        console.log("Old Value:", $element.data('oldVal'));
        console.log("new value:", $element.val());

        // Updated stored value
        $element.data('oldVal', $element.val());

    }
});
```

Here's a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HzkN5/8/

If you view this under IE8 and then click 'reset form' with no other actions a bunch of events hit the console log:

[image]

This is weird because the select's value hasn't been modified at all. This does not occur under the latest Chrome or FireFox.

I was wondering -- why on earth am I seeing the value change so many times? Is there a way to detect only real select value changes?

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out in IE8 its firing the propertychanged event twice whenever the form is reset, but it doesn't fire any actual change events. So, if you just listen to that -- you should be ok :)